# Как переместить значение переменной в константу, а потом подставить в размер массива?

Tags: c++

У меня есть массив
extern int vectorSync[]

После определённых вычислений вычисляется размер массива.
Записывается в переменную.
Но для объявления размера массива, мне надо константу.
Как переместить значение переменной в константу, а потом подставить в размер массива?

Comment: Возможно, стоит задуматься о выборе библиотечного контейнера, например, std::vector

Comment: @Croessmah  std::vector - саморазширяется если индекс массива присваивать больше чем массив инициализирован, или нет? Если нет, нужно допиливать свой класс, или есть реализация "саморасширяемого массива"?

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, не расширится. Для расширения имеются соответствующие функции-члены.

Answer (score 4):

Простите, но вопрос говорит о том, что вы видите чисто внешнюю сторону, не видя сути...

Дело не в том, что размер объявлен как `const`, а в том, что он определяется **во время компиляции**. Если эти вычисления вы можете выполнить во время компиляции - нет проблем, но если не можете - то вот ваш путь:

```
int * vectorSync;

....
n = ....

vectorSync = new int[n];
```

Comment: странно, 
int ArrSize = 9;
int* Arr = new int[ArrSize];
sizeof при любом значении показывает размер 4

Comment: sizeof - показывает размер переменной или типа в байтах. У вас ArrSize - 4-х-байтный int поэтому  sizeof(ArrSize) = sizeof(int) = 4

Comment: Вам нужно понять, что n - это конкретное число, и какое оно должно быть - можно сказать только глядя на задачу. Есть реализации "саморасширяемого массива", но их редко используют т.к. они замедляют работу. Вы можете делать malloc а потом relloc для "разширения". Но саморасширяющийся массив - отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Если вам, например, нужно отсортировать массив из 10 чисел, то n = 10. И так далее, т.е. вначале нужно поставить задачу. Зачем вам нужен массив.

Comment: Естественно, что размер вашего массива в элементах задается значением `n`. `sizeof()` тоже **вычисляется во время компиляции**, так что никак не может применяться к таким вещам, как динамические массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам совсем совсем не нравится ответ с new,

1. Вы можете задать  `int vectorSync[n]` с n = 1000 или 10000 или достаточно большим, таким, которое ваша задача не превысит (есть ограничение на сегмент данных, в 32 битной программе около 1 Гб у меня получилось 10 000 000, в 64 битной гораздо больше). Но более оптимально [2], и [4].
2. Вы можете использовать **new** или *malloc*. malloc делается так

   ```
   int * vectorSync;     
   ....
   vectorSync = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   // или как как вам советовал Harry
   vectorSync = new int[n];
   ```
3. Вы можете задать константу через **предпроцессор** `#define n 1000` или через **константу** `const int n = 5*118*sizeof(int);`, и далее её использовать. `int vectorSync[n];` Из "функций" можно использовать только sizeof - т.к. sizeof - тоже константа. Функцией её не совсем правильно называть.

   Касательно `sizeof` - она нужна в двух случаях. а) Перевести размер в байты (например для `malloc`) б) Померять размер массива  `int nn =sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` в елементах (если опустить знаменатель, получится размер в байтах т.е. [а])
4. Если ну очень хочется функцию с переменным массивом в стеке, и именно массив а не `int *`, можно использовать **шаблоны template**. Но всёравно при подстановки переменной в `<>` - получите ошибку *constant expression* от которой особо избавится не получится. Но можно выкрутится, например так

   ```
   template <int n> f(int nn){
        int vectorSync[n]; 
        }

   void Program(){
     if (n < 10) f<10>(n);
     else if (n < 100) f<100>(n);
     else if (n < 1000) f<1000>(n);
     else {  /*Не хватает памяти*/  }
     }
   ```

   Компилятор создаст 3-ри екземпляра функции, каждая на свой обьем. Похожую конструкцию используют в видеокодеках или декодерах изображений для ускорения. vectorSync в таком случае будет обьявлена в стеке. Я не советую переносить её в сегмент данных (определённым ключевым словом), поскольку память в сегменте данных может тоже закончится, а способ 1 будет более економичным если нужна переменная в сегменте данных.  *Стековая* переменная - означает что она действительна, пока функция, которая её обьявила не сделает `return`.
5. Последний случай, это **внешняя** переменная. Вам нужно или через `#pragma` или через опции компилятора прилинковать библиотеку, которая реализовует данную переменную - тогда её размер будет именно такой, какой в подключенной библиотеке. И вы уже изменить размер не сможете. Так же слово extern позволяет задать размер попозже в соседнем (или в этом же) файле. Т.е.

   ```
   extern int vectorSync[]; // это может быть файл 1 (предопределение)
   ...
   int vectorSync[100];// это может быть как файл 2, так и файл 1.
   ```